# No module named mahotas but it shows installed

Tags: python, pip, installation, importerror, mahotas

I am writing `import mahotas as mt` in my python script. 
I get the error `ImportError: No module named mahotas`

So I used this command to install

```
$ sudo -H pip install mahotas
```

But it gives me the following error

```
Requirement already satisfied: mahotas in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (1.4.5)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from mahotas) (1.16.2)
```

I have no idea what's happening here.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using for code ? If Spyder, try select PYTHONPATH in tools. Add a path to  /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages

Comment: No I am using atom. But when I tried python 3 it worked.

Comment: Of course, if you were using python 2.x, and installed it in python 3.x file ;)